# Mysql FOUND_ROWS with HAVING statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql-calc-found-rows

EDIT: As it turns out, it appears that the code IS running as intended. It was just a debugging issue. Sorry to disturb!

I'm running a large query that involves several filters and JOINs, and also I'm paginating the results therefore the query was running twice.

I tried using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to avoid running the query twice, but since I'm filtering with `HAVING` statements I'm getting the unfiltered total, before the "having statement". I need to run the `HAVING` since the original query relies on counting stuff - which I know is awful but I don't have the permissions to modify the DB structure right now.

An idea of my SQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS u.id as user_id,
               u.full_name as full_name,
               u.email as email,
               COUNT(stuff) as logs,
    FROM
        user u
        LEFT JOIN
        profile u_p on u_p.user_id = u.id 
        GROUP BY u.id 
        HAVING logs>5
    LIMIT 15
```

when I run the new SQL query
`SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total_rows` I get the full amount of `u.id` ROWS and not the filtered one. (This only happens with a `HAVING` statement, and not a `WHERE` clause)

Comment: What are you trying to get from the `LEFT JOIN` here?

Comment: it was just an example SQL in the actual SQL I have a lot more rows selected, some from the profile. Anyhow it was my bad. The code was running as intended

Comment: you can't even bother to write a question property and you're expecting people to understand your problem and help you with it. You're the worst of all people!

Comment: I'm sorry to annoy you. The code I was working with was propietary code and I did my best to try to obscure it enough to  be able to ask this question while at the same time trying to keep the spirit of the code. I didn't realize I wasn't using the u_p on the example I provided. 
Nevertheless I thought the issue was with the "HAVING" because everything else was apparently working. As it turned out, there was no problem at all as I tried to make clear with the EDIT and the "SOLVED" in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it appears that the code IS running as intended. It was just a debugging issue. Sorry to disturb!